How to upgrade CDK Virtual for loop for angular 17
Im upgrading code to angular 17 and needing to update if statements and for loops as i go. I have noticed that if statements and for loops are easy enough but im struggling to move the cdkVirtualFor out into @ annotation.
              <tbody>
                <tr
                  class=border-top border-gray-400 virtual-scroll-row scrollable"
                  def-row
                  *cdkVirtualFor="let entry of entries; index as i; trackBy: track"
                  [entry]="entry"
                  [twid]="'row-' + i"
                ></tr>


I don't think you can, it's a custom structural directive

Ah okay. I was starting to think that
